# csv file not inserting in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $file=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $handle=fopen($file,"r");

    while(($r=fgetcsv($handle,"500",",")) !==FALSE)
    {

    $sql=mysqli_query($con,"insert into `` values('" . implode("','",$r) . "')") or die(mysql_error()) ;

        //echo implode("','",$r); if i run this it shows the data of csv file
    }
}
```

Query is not working. It only shows blank page.

Comment: First of all you mix `mysql_` API and `mysqli_` API. Change: `mysql_error() `to `mysqli_error()`. Then you get the error message

Comment: What about this here: `insert into ''`?

Comment: Second one you have to add a tablename between yout backticks: insert into `<table_name>`

Comment: @Jens done these thing but still no luck

Comment: @A.R Do you get an error message now?

Comment: Your script doesn't echo anything, so you should get a blank page.

Comment: Also Show how you connect to the db

Comment: Are you sure the `if` is matching? Put  `echo "Inserting file into DB";` there so you can be sure.

Comment: Why don't you use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` to send the file directly to MySQL, instead of using your own code to do it?

Comment: @Jens Now getting this error "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1".

Comment: @A.R That means you have more or less columns in the database as in the csv file. Add the column names to the insert Statement like `insert into \`<table_name>\` (col1, col2, ....) values ....`

Comment: @jens I have 13 columns in my file and have 13 fields in my table.

Comment: @A.R You are sure, also no comma in one column?

Comment: @A.R You can print out the Statement before executing, so you can see which line makes the problem

Comment: @jens this is the query before execution-      insert into `coupons` (promoid,offerid,offername,type,code,title,description,category,offerpage,dateadded,expiry,exclusive,featured) values('P42559','2868','Nearbuy.com CPS - India','Promotion','','Flat 40% Off on Domino\"s Pizza Voucher worth Rs 500."','','Food & Beverage','url?offer_id=2868&aff_id=32446','2-Sep-16','31-Dec-16','0','0')

Comment: @A.R are there some single quotes in one string? I can see not the whole query because of the url

Comment: @A.R you should Change to prepared Statements to prevent SQL-injection too.

Comment: @A.R I think a Problem can be the double Qutes in the query. Can you Show the table create Statement?

Comment: @jens create table coupons (promoid VARCHAR(300), offerid VARCHAR(300), offername VARCHAR(300), type VARCHAR(300), code VARCHAR(300), title VARCHAR(300), description VARCHAR(300), category VARCHAR(300), offerpage VARCHAR(300), dateadded VARCHAR(300), expiry VARCHAR(300), exclusive INT(10), featured INT(10))

Comment: @A.R For me it works fine. See this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1a667  But it i copy your insert tatement i see some Special char in it. I have changed it and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

``` insert into `` values ```

`table name` is missing, moreover parse the data, make sure the data that you insert is correct, this can lead to mysql injection as you are passing parameters in the sql statement directly.

Comment: inserted the name of the table and fix the mysql_error() to mysqli_error().. Still no luck

Comment: did you check the record? use try catch